# Xmind 8 doesn't launch

Tags: software-installation

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I have downloaded Xmind zip file and unzipped it. Than started xmind from the folder xmind_amd64.

It's not very elegant, but I'm able to start xmind 8 from other distributions like that (e.g. mx-linux on another machine).

On this machine with 18.04.3 LTS it shows the xmind 8 logo for a few seconds and than brings up an error message which asks me to find out from a log file.
.../xmind-8-update8-linux (1)/workspace/.metadata/.log.
But this log file doesn't exist. (The folder workspace is empty.)

Does anyone has a hint for me how to proceed?

Thanks,
Burkhard

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: XMind 8 only works with jre8, did you install and set it as default?

Comment: @andrew.46 Let me translate from the original German: "An error has occured. In formation abou this can be found at the log file /home/...../xmind-8-update8-linux (1)/workspace/.metadata/.log"

Comment: @Alvin Liang Thanks for your advise. I took it to install the latest java-jre-ondra. It doesn't change the error occuring. (Though, I didn't know how to" set it as  default.")

Comment: You misunderstood me. Default/Latest versions in 18.04 will not work. You need JDK 8.0, the old one.

Comment: 1. Check jre 8 is installed, if not, run `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre`
2. Check if it's default java by `java -version`.  If not 1.8.0_xxxx, use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and change your java verison.

Comment: @Alvin Liang
You are absolutely wonderful!! Thank you so much. It worked exactly as you have instructed. This made my day!